# No matching version found for my-other-package@0.0.0-0

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning, lerna

I'm working with a `lerna` project that uses `npm` and uncertain whether this is a lerna or npm issue.

The structure of the project is like this

```
- package.json (root)
- package-lock.json
- lerna.json
- packages/
  - main-package/
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - ...
  - aux-package/
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - ...
```

In `main-package/package.json`, there is a localPeerDependencies entry

```
"localPeerDependencies": {
    "aux-package": "0.0.0-0",
    ...
  }
```

and aux-package's version field matches that value.

Inside the `main-package` directory, I can run the build script just fine and things work correctly. However, I've modified the code so that `aux-package` is no longer needed as a dependency and thus the peerLocalDependencies entry can can be deleted.

Running `npm remove aux-package` gives me the following error

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for aux-package@0.0.0-0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Running `npm prune` gives the same error.

I suppose I could manually delete the relevant entries in package.json, package-lock.json, then remove the node_modules folder and reinstall. However I'm hoping to really understand the underlying problem.

First off, is this a `lerna` issue or `npm`?
Secondly, what is "the right way" to uninstall packages in `localPeerDependencies` in the year 2023?

Thank you in advance for any pointers in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main-package`, it looks like package.json, package-lock.json, and node_modules/.package-lock.json just got out of sync so the error was just the result of that.

To fix this, I had to the following 1 time to get the correct linkages back:

```
rm -rf node_modules. #at the main-package level

lerna link #at the project root level

npm install # at the main-package level
```

Seem to be smooth sailing from there.